# Get user setting from chache don`t work in WPF MVVM C#

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I like to save the user input to the user settings and after every restart of the app I like that they get the "new" string from the settings.

But everytime the user settings proparty are empty. Don`t know why. Can someone help me?

Here is compressed code:

View Datacontext is in the code behinde:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <m:Model x:Key="model"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<TextBox x:Name="txtbx_user" Text="{Binding UserName}"/>
```

Model:

```
private string _userName;

        public string UserName
        {
            get
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Properties.Settings.Default.UserName))
                {
                    return Properties.Settings.Default.UserName;
                }
                else
                {
                    return _userName;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                _userName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("UserName");
                Properties.Settings.Default.UserName = _userName;
            }
        }
```

And yes I have the already set the string in the properties of the project.

Why I have every time if I restart the app a empty string in the Properties.Settings.Default.UserName

Thank you guys!

Comment: Check that your setting whcih you want update is defined with User level.. and also don't forget call  Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by [Anton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3360687/anton), you're missing the *Save* statement once changes have taken place.

```
Properties.Settings.Default.UserName = _userName;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```